# Why isn't <name> metadata added to child pom files generated by the flatten-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, parent-pom, flatten-maven-plugin

The output pom files generated by the flatten-maven-plugin(v 1.0.1) contains all the metadata elements I need to publish on OSSRH when `<flattenMode>ossrh</flattenMode>` is specified, or when individual fields are specified with `<pomElements>`. However, the flattened child poms in my project are missing one element required by OSSRH: the project `<name>`. The flattened parent pom does contain `<name>`.

My original issue is described in [How to resolve parent pom dependency issue: Failed to read artifact descriptor; Could not find artifact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173260/how-to-resolve-parent-pom-dependency-issue-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor), which worked. The final workaround is described in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173260/how-to-resolve-parent-pom-dependency-issue-failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor#comment91464209_52173650), but I'm wondering if this workaround is actually necessary (or, maybe it is even a bug, since it seems unlikely all the other metadata elements would be copied over without issue).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in flatten-maven-plugin. Have you filed in an issue on the project?

Comment: OK, added it at https://github.com/mojohaus/flatten-maven-plugin/issues/76